# web3 - Error while calling smart contract pure function via web3 using nodejs?

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

This is my smart contract written in solidity (v.0.5.16) -

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract MyContract {
    function myFunction() public pure returns(uint256 myNumber, string memory myString) {
        return (23456, "Hello!%");
    }
}
```

This is my web3 (v.1.2.6) code written in NodeJS (v.10.16.1) -

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));

const abi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"myFunction","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"myNumber","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"myString","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}];

const address = '0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a';
const default_address = '0x597c0d6383aAEad3895Ee8191F4eF2Dd8940B6E7';

const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
myContract.deploy({
      data: '0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5061012f806100206000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c8063c3780a3a14602d575b600080fd5b603360b2565b6040518083815260200180602001828103825283818151815260200191508051906020019080838360005b838110156077578082015181840152602081019050605e565b50505050905090810190601f16801560a35780820380516001836020036101000a031916815260200191505b50935050505060405180910390f35b60006060615ba08090506040518060400160405280600781526020017f48656c6c6f21250000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000081525091509150909156fea265627a7a723158207c74308dd7b2369a27728a1c18b137dbf8de6f83a3015e84d898f4312374719764736f6c63430005100032'
    })
    .send({
      from: default_address,    
      gas: 1500000,
      gasPrice: '30000000000000'
    }).then(function(newContractInstance){
        console.log("contract address -");
        console.log(newContractInstance.options.address); // instance with the new contract address
});

myContract.methods.myFunction().call()
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

It prints the value of `newContractInstance.options.address` but gives this **ERROR on `call()`** -

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (...\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:239:15)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (...\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:557:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (...\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\src\index.js:910:46)
    at Method.formatOutput (...\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:167:54)
    at sendTxCallback (...\node_modules\web3-core-method\src\index.js:596:33)
    at ...\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\src\index.js:147:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (...\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:110:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (...\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (...\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (...\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Comment: You should do the call to `myContract.methods.myFunction` inside `function(newContractInstance)`. Otherwise, you are doing it without waiting for the contract deployment to complete.

Comment: Use 'await' dude...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change this:

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

To this:

```
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);
```

You should not provide an address when deploying a contract, since the address of that contract is obviously not viable until you have deployed it.

Second, change this:

```
myContract.methods.myFunction().call()
```

To this:

```
newContractInstance.methods.myFunction().call()
```

Because the `myContract` object does not hold a deployed contract, but the `newContractInstance` object does.

Of course, you'll need to make that call from inside `function(newContractInstance)`, otherwise, you are doing it without waiting for the contract deployment to complete.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I did those two changes mentioned above. Now I'm getting a new ERROR - `Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at Object.ErrorResponse...`. I haven't changed the smart contract. There are no modifiers or `require()` in the contract.

Comment: @surhud004: Before posting this answer, I have actually tried your code with the changes that I later suggested here, and it worked fine. Please make sure that you are applying **the exact same changes**.

Comment: Yes, I did the exact changes. Here's the code snippet - `.then(function(newContractInstance){
  console.log("contract address -");
     console.log(newContractInstance.options.address); // instance with the new contract address
  
  newContractInstance.methods.myFunction().call()
  .then(function(result){
   console.log(result);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
});`

Comment: Here's the complete code snippet with the ERROR snippet - https://gist.github.com/surhud004/59f876f6f991941e2145e9cbca2f6134

Comment: @surhud004: The bytecode in that link is different from the bytecode in your questio!!! A simple comparison of the two code snippets (as I just did) would have revealed that to you. You should be more meticulous when writing your code!

Comment: Oh no!! My mistake. I am working on solidity for the first time. Yes, it works!! Thanks a lot for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: I cannot since I am a new contributor. You need more than 50 reputation to accept that. Apologies.